# Crash in hash_table STL C++

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, hashmap

Im developing library c++ in android app by JNI.
Im using std::unordered_map and std::unordered_set for storage and access data.
I have a mData which is blacklist data. Then when I add new word in blacklist data, it make app crashed and push crash info in fabric.

App crash sometime and some device. I can't reprocude issue. So sad.

```
struct CodePoints {
    explicit CodePoints() { }

    explicit CodePoints(const int * codePoints, const int codePointsCount) {
        mCodePoints.insert(mCodePoints.end(), codePoints, codePoints + codePointsCount);
    }

    explicit CodePoints(const std::vector<int>& codePoints) {
        mCodePoints.insert(mCodePoints.end(), codePoints.begin(), codePoints.end());
    }

    CodePoints(const CodePoints & rhs) {
        mCodePoints.insert(mCodePoints.end(), rhs.mCodePoints.begin(), rhs.mCodePoints.end());
    }

    virtual ~CodePoints() {}

    CodePoints & operator=(const CodePoints& rhs) {
        if (this != &rhs) {
            mCodePoints.assign(rhs.mCodePoints.begin(), rhs.mCodePoints.end());
        }
        return *this;
    }
    bool operator==(const CodePoints& rhs) const {
        if (codePointsCount() != rhs.codePointsCount()) {
            return false;
        }
        int size = codePointsCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++ i) {
            if ( this->get(i) != rhs.get(i) ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    friend struct std::hash<CodePoints>;
    template< class InputIt, class UnaryFunction > friend
    UnaryFunction for_each( InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryFunction f );

    std::vector<int> mCodePoints;
};

#define MAX_SIZE_BLACKLIST_DICT 20000
typedef std::unordered_set<CodePoints> BlacklistType;

    BlacklistType mData;
    int mSize;

    void BlacklistMapper::addWord(CodePoints word) {
        if(mSize >= MAX_SIZE_BLACKLIST_DICT) {
            AKLOGE("Max size Blacklist. Can not add new word into blacklist");
            return;
        };
        mData.insert(word);
        mSize++;
    }
 struct hash<CodePoints>
{
    size_t operator()(const CodePoints& codePoints) const
    {
        size_t hashCode{0};
        for_each(codePoints.mCodePoints.begin(), codePoints.mCodePoints.end(), [&hashCode](int codePoint){ hashCode = 31 * hashCode + codePoint; });
        return hashCode;
    }
};
```

This is crash infomation in fabric

```
0  libjni_labanime_v1_4_1.so      0xca9e4ffa latinime::BlacklistMapper::addWord(latinime::CodePoints) (__hash_table:102)
1  (Missing)                      0xecd656df (Missing)
2  libjni_labanime_v1_4_1.so      0xca9e0b19 latinime::latinime_BlacklistMapper_addWord(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jintArray*) (com_android_inputmethod_latin_BlacklistMapper.cpp:29)
3  libjni_labanime_v1_4_1.so      0xca9e0a99 latinime::latinime_BlacklistMapper_addWord(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jintArray*) (jni.h:854)
4  (Missing)                      0xecd656df (Missing)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Post a [MCVE]..

Comment: Im using stl "c++_static" flag in gradle

Comment: If the key already exists then the insertion will fail and the size will not change. Why do you keep your own `mSize` when you can just use `mData.size()` to get the *actual* size?

Comment: Thank @JiveDadson, I updated my question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok thank you. This is my mistake. But actualy this thing dont make crash. I think so because I know key not exist. I have list bad word.

Comment: Unless you use `mSize` as an index somewhere else, and it might get out of bounds, then no it's most likely not involved in the crash. It is a logical error though, and might lead to mistakes or problems elsewhere.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude. Thank you for your help. I fixed. But I know the key already not exists because I have list key.

Comment: @huynguyen Seriously, stop the `mSize` stuff.  Having extraneous variables to denote sizes that are already known by the container is a source of bugs.  Use the `size()` member function that the container gives you -- it never is wrong.  Second, check the return value of `insert()`.  It will tell you whether the new value is inserted or not.

Comment: Yes, I fixed. @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: I just can't shake the feeling that's something's a little... "off" with the code you show. It could be the `CodePoints` constructors not being very good, or the fact that we don't have all information (what is `toLowerCase`? What does your `std::hash<CodePoints>` do?) but your code makes my brain itch.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for your help. I updated my question with hash CodePoint and remove toLowerCase. Im sure about toLowerCase dont make my app crash. Thanks again.

Comment: Are you sure there is just one thread accessing the object?

Comment: UPDATED. init in another thread and using another thread.